# Use transaction to batch updates to SQLite

Tags: c#, system.data.sqlite, microsoft.data.sqlite

I get an error using `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` to add products to a SQLite database in a loop. The error:

```
Must add values for the following parameters: @ItemCode, @ItemCost, @ItemDescription, @LocationId, @ReorderStockLevel, @ReservedStockLevel, @StockLevel, @StockIt, @SupplierId
```

In my code I try to follow the examples at [Bulk Insert in Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://www.bricelam.net/2017/07/20/sqlite-bulk-insert.html) and [Bulk insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/bulk-insert)

```
using (SqliteConnection con = new(DataService.SqliteConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqliteTransaction transaction = con.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (SqliteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText =
                    $"INSERT INTO Products 
                        (
                        ItemCode, 
                        ItemCost, 
                        ItemDescription, 
                        LocationId, 
                        ReorderStockLevel, 
                        ReservedStockLevel, 
                        StockLevel, 
                        StockIt, 
                        SupplierId
                        ) 
                    VALUES 
                        (
                        @ItemCode, 
                        @ItemCost, 
                        @ItemDescription, 
                        @LocationId, 
                        @ReorderStockLevel, 
                        @ReservedStockLevel, 
                        @StockLevel, 
                        @StockIt, 
                        @SupplierId
                        )";

            SqliteParameter itemCodeParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
            itemCodeParam.ParameterName = "$ItemCode";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(itemCodeParam);

            SqliteParameter itemCostParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
            itemCostParam.ParameterName = "$ItemCost";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(itemCostParam);

            SqliteParameter itemDescriptionParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
            itemDescriptionParam.ParameterName = "$ItemDescription";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(itemDescriptionParam);

            SqliteParameter locationIdParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
            locationIdParam.ParameterName = "$LocationId";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(locationIdParam);

            SqliteParameter reorderStockLevelParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
            reorderStockLevelParam.ParameterName = "$ReorderStockLevel";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(reorderStockLevelParam);

            SqliteParameter reservedStockLevelParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
            reservedStockLevelParam.ParameterName = "$ReservedStockLevel";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(reservedStockLevelParam);

            SqliteParameter stockLevelParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
            stockLevelParam.ParameterName = "$StockLevel";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(stockLevelParam);

            SqliteParameter stockItParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
            stockItParam.ParameterName = "$StockIt";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(stockItParam);

            SqliteParameter supplierIdParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
            supplierIdParam.ParameterName = "$SupplierId";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(supplierIdParam);

            foreach (Product newItem in newItems)
            {
                itemCodeParam.Value = newItem.ItemCode;
                itemCostParam.Value = newItem.ItemCost;
                itemDescriptionParam.Value = newItem.ItemDescription;
                locationIdParam.Value = newItem.LocationId;
                reorderStockLevelParam.Value = newItem.ReorderStockLevel;
                reservedStockLevelParam.Value = newItem.ReservedStockLevel;
                stockItParam.Value = newItem.StockIt;
                stockLevelParam.Value = newItem.StockLevel;
                supplierIdParam.Value = newItem.SupplierId;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            cmd.Prepare();
            transaction.Commit();            
        }
    }
}
```

The first call to `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` fires. The exception throws as `foreach (Product newItem in newItems)` is entered for the second iteraton .The same exception throws with and without `cmd.Prepare()`

No products are entered into the database. The database connection configuration is correct as products can be entered in the database row at a time.

How to I update a list of items in a transaction?

Comment: The insert `sql` ends with two close parenthesis! `INSERT INTO .... ))`. Check that out

Comment: @dr.null thank you for bringing the double parenthesis to my attention. That was a typo when writing the question. I've edited the sql to hopefully make it more legible.

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but cmd.Prepare() should be called once, outside the loop.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thank for the advice. I've moved `cmd.Prepare` outside the 'foreach' loop. The error is the same

Comment: Just replace the `@` signs in the sql with `$` signs.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft please propose replacing `@` with `$` so I can accept.